How to press 'Enter' after text input is given in the search filed in dropdown using selenium webdriver
I am trying to write python script using WebDriver for data scrapping
In the case I am trying to open a browser, click the dropdown using xpath, then entering the 'input'(emissor_item) since the dropdown contains the search box.
Once the first data is entered, I would like to click Enter on keyboard and wait till loads then extract the publications associated with the input.
I am successful in clearing the pre-search and entering text but not sure how to write code to press 'Enter key' or Enter, please advise. i tried submit button, bo.find_element_by_name and java trigger. but nothing work.
Apologies, I could not find this in search.
Thanks in advance,
        
        if any(item in all_drop_down_lists for item in to_select):
            
            for emissor_item in to_select:

                # Find the search button by its XPath 
                xpath = '//*[@id="b8-ArtigoDropDown4"]'
                clickableElement = BO.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath)
                # Click on the search button
                clickableElement.click()
                
                
                
                # Find the input field for the dropdown search
                search_input = BO.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="b8-ArtigoDropDown4"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/input')  # Replace 'search_input_id' with the actual id or other locator of the search input field
                # Clear any existing text
                search_input.clear()
                # Input the emissor_item into the search box
                search_input.send_keys(emissor_item)
                
                #click the enter button

                time.sleep(1) ```


you can use from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys and from it use search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).

You can use Keys.ENTER to send Enter key:
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


element = ... # some element
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

